# Redrawing a SFAuthorizationPluginView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sfauthorizationpluginview

I'm writing a custom AuthenticationPlugin which has some dynamic content (currently in the form of labels). I'd like to be able to update the labels in response to events.

Assuming the following declarations:

- `parent = SFAuthorizationPluginView (subclass)`

  - `view = NSView (subclass)`

    - `NSTextField *label = ...`

I edit the label text as follows (note: this may be executed from the background dispatch queue):
`[label setStringValue:@"new text"];`

I then try to force an update using the following:

- `[label setNeedsDisplay:YES];`
- `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [label setNeedsDisplay:YES]; });`
- `[label display];`
- `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [label display]; });`
- `[[label cell] update];`
- `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [[label cell] update]; });`
- `[[label cell] needsDisplay];`
- `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [[label cell] needsDisplay]; });`
- `[view setNeedsDisplay:YES];`
- `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [view setNeedsDisplay:YES]; });`
- `[self updateView];`
- `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self updateView]; });`
- `[self displayView]`
- `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self displayView]; });`

However, I get a mixture of no action and flickering grey screen (indicating I've caused an exception).

Any ideas? (Note: I'll be editing this question as I try various options)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need to do is put the update of the label in the main queue code like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 label.text = "Hello World!";
});
```